# Address already in use error when using a socket server and a flask webserver in the same script (python)

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I'm studying cybersecurity in college and I'm interested in malware and that type of stuff. Out of curiosity, I'm trying to write a botnet + control server to learn more about how they work. My control server consists of a thread with a socket server and a flask REST API for issuing commands. The flask API runs fine without the socket listener running, and vise versa. But if I try to run the flask api and the socket listener at the same time, I get `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

I'm binding my socket with `sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 6505))` and starting my flask server with `app.run("0.0.0.0", 6506)`

I'm also using `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`

Things I've tried:

- Changing both the socket and the flask to a different port
- Using different bind addresses on the socket and flask (socket=0.0.0.0, flask=127.0.0.1, etc)
- Running both (flask & socket) on localhost (127.0.0.1)
- checking lsof to see if there's anything else running on those ports
- killing all other running python processes
- Checked for duplicate code (no dup binds)

Update:
Something weird happens, If I run the flask server first, I get no error, but the socket server doesn't start. However, if I run the socket server first, I get the error, and neither of them run

Update2: Here's some of my code:

Update3:
I tried moving the flask webserver into the thread and moving my socket listener but it seems like the webserver is blocking my listener. When I switched them, I got no error and lsof reports both ports have a python process listening on them, I can connect with the webserver but the socket seems to timeout, but not instantly. The sockets definitely running, but it seems like it can't run any code for some reason. I

Update4: I tried putting some print statements in my function that sets up the socket server, and it turns out its running twice because of the flask severs auto-reload! I think I need to disable auto-reload and it'll solve my issue

```py
### WEB ROUTES ###
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/ping", methods=["POST"])
def ping():
    return "FAKE PING"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((self.HOST, self.PORT))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.listen(0)
sock.settimeout(10)
# Thread that handles new client connections
listen_thread = Thread(target=listen)
listen_thread.start()

app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.run("0.0.0.0", 5407)
```

BTW, I don't care if I'm not doing this in the best possible way, I'm just using this project to learn, it means nothing.

I'm also kinda a noob with sockets, so ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Am I doing something wrong or is there something about networking I don't understand?

Comment: Run them each on their own localhost port, eg socket on 127.0.0.1:6000 and flask/werkzeug server on 127.0.0.1:5000 and tell us what happens.

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 same issue :(

Comment: Do you know which one causes the error? Try and start them *not* at the same time, and see if the error comes only when you run the second one. If the error is raised when you run the first, that means something else is running on your port.

Comment: Something weird happens, If I run the flask server first, I get no error, but the socket server doesn't start. However, if I run the socket server first, I get the error, and neither of them run

Comment: Perhaps you have a duplicate line in your socket starting code which starts the server? So when you run it, it starts it twice meaning the second one raises an `OSError`. Unfortunately you haven't provided much code, so I can't help you much

Comment: I'll update the question with more code! @monsieuralfonse64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221482/discussion-between-monsieuralfonse64-and-steven-tautonico).

Comment: Run one of your servers then check which ports are active e.g. use `netstat -a -p tcp` to see what ports that uses. Then stop that server and start the other and repeat the check.

Comment: @barny tried that already, no dice

Comment: Please summarise in your question other things you’ve tried. Helps avoid wasting reader’s time and this background info should always be in your questions.

Comment: You’re going to have to post __minimal__ code for both servers as a   [mre] to check if someone else can reproduce the problem using your code. I’m guessing they won’t, but without that check this is all just speculation.

Answer (score 0):

The flask auto-reload causes the code to restart without closing the original socket, so the socket was trying to bind to the address/port a second time. To solve this, I disabled the reloader using this:

```py
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
run_simple("0.0.0.0", 5407, app, use_reloader=False)
```